# select.getElementsByTagName except for a certain option

Tags: javascript

[Option List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cetfL.png)

I have an problem where my Random Option Picker picks a certain `option` that I don't want. How do I mitigate this?

```
var select = document.getElementById('edit-categories');
var items = select.getElementsByTagName('option');
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length + 1);
return select.selectedIndex = index;
```

The `option` that I want my random picker to ommit is : `value="_none"`

Comment: You shouldn't link to code in pictures.

Comment: It's simpler to use the select's *options* collection: `var items = select.options`. ;-)

Comment: So do not include zero....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, you can also use *Array.prototype.filter* (since It's a lot easier to [pollyfil *filter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill) than the `[not]` selector):

```js
var opts = [].filter.call(document.getElementById('edit-categories').options, function(opt){return opt.value != '_none'})

console.log(opts);
```

```html
<select id="edit-categories">
  <option value="_none">None
  <option value="foo">Foo
  <option value="foo">Bar
</select>
```

Comment: This is the one I am looking for. Thank you So much.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) along with [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
var items = select.querySelectorAll('option:not([value="_none"])');
```

```js
var select = document.querySelector('select');
var items = select.querySelectorAll('option:not([value="_none"])');
console.log(items);
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="_none">--</option>
  <option value="water">Water</option>
  <option value="waste">Waste</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Cool solution...not often you see people using the `:not` selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `while` loop just before setting the index :

```js
var select = document.getElementById('edit-categories');
var items = select.getElementsByTagName('option');
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
while (items[index].value == '_none') {
    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
}
select.selectedIndex = index;
```

```html
  <select id="edit-categories">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="_none">none</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
```